# How to send send UTC Now time in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I'm working on API load testing and my current local timezone is IST (India Standard Time) UTC+5:30. The API used for store offline data and android developers are sending record created time in UTC Time. So, API developer asks me to send created time same as android developer sends in UTC time rather than local time.

My question is "How can send UTC Now time or convert local time to UTC timezone?". I don't have any idea to do this.

I tried this solution [jmeter convert date from EST to UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18007111/jmeter-convert-date-from-est-to-utc), but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `JSR223 PreProcessor` to generate the UTC timezone based upon your current time before the request

Add the below code to your preprocessor

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;

String localDateTime3  = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC-05:30")).toString();
println("Date for the UTC time zone: " + localDateTime3);
vars.put('date',localDateTime3);
println(vars.get('date'))
```

Now you can use `${date}` in your request payload to send the date data

**Reference:** https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/creating-and-testing-dates-in-jmeter-learn-how/

Comment: Tried this solution but the UTC Time seems to send wrongly as "2020-03-13T22:47:59.788" while developer says actual UTC time is "2020-03-14T04:17:59".

Answer (score 1):

You can use [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) to generate the current time in the given time zone like:

```
${__groovy(new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss"\, TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC')),)}
```

Demo:

[image]

References:

- [Groovy Date](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)